# How to Insert a Hyphen after the second character of a INPUT TEXT and allow only numbers from user

Tags: javascript, html

The user has to fill an input with an internal document number. The format of the document is 00-0000 (where after the hyphen, there are different numbers of characters.

It can be: `00-000`

OR: `00-0000`

OR: `00-00000...0`

My issues:

1. How to insert this HYPHEN automatically when the users types only
   numbers.
2. How can my input accept only numbers from user but accept this "-"
       automatically inserted?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think you can try with two input boxes and join their value by '-' using javascript.

Comment: You need to make an attempt at solving this, and if you already have, please post your code. We're not code monkeys that will solve any problem thrown at us. For that, you can hire a developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example for you :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).delegate(".code","keydown",function(e) {
        if (
            $.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
            (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
            (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
                return;
        }

        if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        if($(e.target).val().length == 2) {
            e.target.value = e.target.value + "-";
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" class="code" value="" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using external libraries, I would bind a function to the onkeyup-event of the input. The function would check the value of the input against an regular expression allowing only the desired format. If the last keystroke didn't match the pattern, the value of the input get's the last character cut off.

A second task for the function would be to add the hyphen as soon as the values length equals 2.

There's a lot of information on how to use regular expressions within JavaScript. Google will certainly help finding suitable tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this is proper solution, but you can try this out.
HTML:-

```
<label>Enter Doc Number</label>
<input type="number" id="leading">
<input type="number" id="trailing">
<button onclick="getDocNumber()">DOC Numbers</button>
```

JavaScript:-

```
function getDocNumber(){
        var leading = document.getElementById('leading').value;
        var trailing = document.getElementById('trailing').value;
        var docNO = leading + "-" + trailing;
        alert(docNO);
    }
```